# react-navigation-camera conflict with react-navigation-stack and

Tags: node.js, react-native, camera, navigation, stack

I'm trying to add react-navigation-camera into my react native project. But after executing

```
npm install react-native-camera --save
react-native link react-native-camera
```

some packages will be removed. and

```
npm ERR!     Missing: @react-native-community/masked-view@^0.1.6
npm ERR!     Missing: react-native-gesture-handler@^1.5.3
npm ERR!     Missing: react-native-reanimated@^1.7.0
npm ERR!     Missing: react-navigation-drawer@^2.3.3
npm ERR!     Missing: react-navigation-stack@^2.0.15
```

happened!

**How can I use this packages all together?**

Comment: what version of RN are you using?

Comment: @GauravRoy "react": "16.9.0",   "react-native": "0.61.5",

Comment: you dont have to type react-native link react-native-camera

Comment: @GauravRoy I tried that without `link` but problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont have to type `react-native link react-native-camera` , its autolinked after 0.60 >  , so try first `react-native unlink react-native-camera` and try using directly in your code.

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: I tried that without `link` but problem still exists.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Those packages was removed!

Comment: so do a thing now, first delete your whole node modules folder , and delete the npm.lock file and then do npm i , now it should work